# Find object in state and update property

Tags: reactjs, state, onchange

I have a problem with a dynamic state I am setting. My first state looks like this:

```
const [exercises, setExercises] = useState([{
  id: 123,
  title: "Title here",
  category: "someCategory"
}])
```

A user then selects an item of this state. I create a second state representing the selected object, but adding additional properties to it. For instance I am adding and initializing the properties 'amount' and 'unit'.

```
const [selectedExercises, setSelectedExercises] = useState([{
  id: 123,
  title: "Title here",
  category: "someCategory",
  amount: 0,
  unit: ''
}])
```

I want the user to choose amount and unit from a form. How do I access and change those two properties in the state? Since I don't know the user's selection, I have to find the object within the state first.

I have tried things like (`el` being called from an input element somewhere):

```
setSelectedExercises([
  ...selectedExercises,
  (selectedExercises.find(exercise => exercise.title === el.title).amount = 1),
  ])
```

How do I find the object in question and update its amount property (for example in an onChange method)?

Comment: can you add your component too?

Comment: Read about prevState and actually you should mutate your data outside this function and later use them in setSelectedExercies

Comment: can you please add more about  what you did ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const [selectedExercises, setSelectedExercises] = useState([{
  id: 123,
  title: "Title here",
  category: "someCategory",
  amount: 0,
  unit: ''
}]);

// Your handler should look like this and 
// you should call handleAmountChange(el.id, 1)

function handleAmountChange(amount, id) {
  setSelectedExercises(prev => prev.map(selectedExercise => {
    if (selectedExercise.id === id) {
      return {
        ...selectedExercise,
        amount
      }
    }

    return selectedExercise;
  }));
}
```

A more generic function to change any property would look like this.

```js
function handleChange(id, property, value) {
  setSelectedExercises(prev => prev.map(selectedExercise => {
    if (selectedExercise.id === id) {
      return {
        ...selectedExercise,
        [property]: value
      }
    }

    return selectedExercise;
  }));
}
```